# Calendar In C Programming Language Assignment

Tags: function, calendar, printf, scanf

Have been working on this assignment for 20+ hours and I understand people for some reason never want to help with homework assignments but I literally am not getting anywhere and figured I would at least TRY and ask for help because I have tried on multiple forums to no avail. My code is as follows...

```html
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int getdaycode(int month,  int year);
void printheader(int month, int year);
int getndim(int month, int year);

int main()
{
 int  day, month, year, nummonths;
 {
  printf("Enter Month, Year, and Number of Months");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &year, &nummonths);
  
  for (nummonths; nummonths < 13; nummonths++)
   if (nummonths > 13)
    year = year + 1;

  printheader(month, year);
  int numdays = getndim(month, year);
  int daycode = getdaycode(month,  year);
  
  for (day = 1; day <= 1 + daycode * 4; day++)
   printf(" ");
  
  for (day = 1; day <= numdays; day++) 
  
  {
   printf("%2d", day);
   if ((day + daycode) % 7 > 0)

    printf("   ");
   else
    printf("\n");
  }
  daycode = (daycode + numdays) % 7;
 }
}


int getdaycode(int month, int year)
{
 int numdays;
 {
  numdays = ((year - 1) * 365 + ((year - 1) / 4) - ((year - 1) / 100) + ((year - 1) / 400)); // how many days including exceptions

  if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))  //check if leapyear
  {
   if (month == 1)       // January 
    numdays = numdays;
   if (month == 2)       // February 
    numdays = numdays + 31;
   if (month == 3)       // March 
    numdays = numdays + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 4)       // April 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 5)       // May 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 6)       // June 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 7)       // July 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 8)       // August 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 9)       // September 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 10)       // October      
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 11)       // November
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
   if (month == 12)       // December
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31 + 1;
  }
  else
  {
   if (month == 1)       // January 
    numdays = numdays;
   if (month == 2)       // February 
    numdays = numdays + 31;
   if (month == 3)       // March 
    numdays = numdays + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 4)       // April 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 5)       // May 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 6)       // June 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 7)       // July 
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 8)       // August 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 9)       // September 
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 10)       // October      
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 11)       // November
    numdays = numdays + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
   if (month == 12)       // December
    numdays = numdays + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 28 + 31;
  }

  int daycode = numdays % 7;
  switch (daycode)
  {
  case 0:
   printf("Sunday\n");
   break;

  case 1:
   printf("Monday\n");
   break;

  case 2:
   printf("Tuesday\n");
   break;

  case 3:
   printf("Wednesday\n");
   break;

  case 4:
   printf("Thursday\n");
   break;

  case 5:
   printf("Friday\n");
   break;

  case 6:
   printf("Saturday\n");
   break;

  default: printf("unexpected error (daycode case) daycode = %d", daycode);
   break;
  }
  return daycode;
 }
}

void printheader(int month, int year)
 {
   printf("%14d %1d\n", month, year);
   printf("Sun ");
   printf("Mon ");
   printf("Tue ");
   printf("Wed ");
   printf("Thu ");
   printf("Fri ");
   printf("Sat\n");
  }

int getndim(int month, int year)
{
 int numdays;
 if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))  //check if leapyear
 {
  if (month == 1)       // January 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 2)       // February 
   numdays = 29;
  if (month == 3)       // March 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 4)       // April 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 5)       // May 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 6)       // June 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 7)       // July 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 8)       // August 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 9)       // September 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 10)       // October      
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 11)       // November
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 12)       // December
   numdays = 31;
 }
 else
 {
  if (month == 1)       // January 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 2)       // February 
   numdays = 28;
  if (month == 3)       // March 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 4)       // April 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 5)       // May 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 6)       // June 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 7)       // July 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 8)       // August 
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 9)       // September 
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 10)       // October      
   numdays = 31;
  if (month == 11)       // November
   numdays = 30;
  if (month == 12)       // December
   numdays = 31;
 }
 return numdays;
}
```

[image]

What I am wondering is how to call my getdaycode function correctly into my main function. Also, when that isn't the problem, the day keeps showing up below my header and it messes with the ordering of the days messing up the calendar. Those are my two biggest problems at this point, I really would enjoy working through this with someone... Really confused.. and before you say look back at your material.. I am brand new at programming with no background, as well as this course didn't come with any sources such as books or sites to reference. (This makes it EXTREMELY difficult). Any help Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: "I understand people for some reason never want to help with homework assignments" - This is not true. What people don't want is write code for slackers. [Here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) the accepted policy on homework: don't solve, do *help* solve. As for your question, a bit more details would be nice. For example, "how to call my getdaycode function correctly into my main function" - what is wrong with the way you call it now?

Comment: "the day keeps showing up below my header and it messes with the ordering of the days messing up the calendar" - show the output in your question, don't make people compile - and show how you'd *like* it to be as well (to keep us from guessing what you want). Describe also what the program is *for*. A good question goes a long way towards getting good answers.

Comment: I don't know how to post my output / result of what shows up during debug

Comment: Just click "edit" beneath your question and copy-paste it in.

Comment: That Saturday gets in the way, and when my days get to Saturday they are not \n or going to the next line. The spacing between the days and the header space is correct however.

Comment: Also don't forget to put in the description and a sample of what you *do* want the output to look like. For all we know, what your screenshot says is exactly what the assignment wants you to do. Do you want the "Saturday" there? Do you want it elsewhere? Do you want it not being printed? As to why you don't get newlines - `daycode` doesn't change in your loop, so your `if` ends up being either always true or always false. You probably want to test `daycode + day` or something similar.

Comment: Ok, I'll try doing something like that, and I'm not sure how I would get a picture of what my output is "supposed" to look like. That picture seems like it is self explanatory after hears that the Saturday was not supposed to be there, and that I wanted the day numbers to go \n when they reach Sat like a normal calender would do with this layout.

Comment: Don't use picture. Use text. Whatever you indent by 4 spaces is laid out in your question exactly like you write it. If you don't want "Saturday" to be printed... not printing it is an easy solution. And I told you what to do about the newlines.

Comment: Woah it is looking better but Saturday is still there. I don't understand how to get rid of it, you said "Do you want the "Saturday" there? Do you want it elsewhere? Do you want it not being printed?" Not sure how that explains how to get rid of it. but thanks for the tip on checking Daycode + day

Comment: "Saturday" is being printed by `printf("Saturday")`. If you delete the whole `switch` statement from `getdaycode`, it won't get printed any more. You know that joke, "Doctor, it hurts me when I do this" - "Did you consider not doing that?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may help and useful for you .

```
int main()
{
int  day, month, year, nummonths;
    printf("Enter Month, Year, and Number of Months");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &year, &nummonths);
    if (nummonths > 12)
        year = year + nummonths%12;

    printheader(month, year);
    int numdays = getndim(month, year);
    int daycode = getdaycode(month, day, year);

   for (day = 1; day <= numdays; day++) 
    {   printf("%4d", day);
        if (day % 7 > 0)
            printf("\t");
        else
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

but apart form solution of that specific problem you need work on some skills that can help you .

Please prefer some book and online resources and complete any one of them

1> Book :- let us c ,By:- balaguruswami

2> Tutorials http://www.w3schools.in/c/intro/

3> Tutorials http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/

Comment: Cool thanks that is the formatting that I am working on now. just curious, I know \n is new line, what does \t mean?

Comment: Also, why is it that I am getting a local error with the 'int daycode = getdaycode(month, day, year);'

Comment: Never mind, ok thanks, I guess I could just elminate the day from my getdaycode function maybe

Answer (score 1):

```
int getndim(int month, int year)
{
int numdays;            
        //---whatever your code is
    if(check condition)     
    {
        if (month == 2)                         
            numdays = 29;   
    }
    return numdays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int getdaycode(int month, int day, int year)
{
    int numdays;
    numdays = (whatever it is); // how many days including exceptions
            if (month == 1)                         
                numdays = numdays;
            if (month == 2)                         
                numdays = numdays + 31;
            if (month == 3)                         
                numdays = numdays + 28 + 31;
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
        if (check condition )       //check if leapyear
        {
            if (month == 1 || month == 2)                           // January 
                numdays = numdays;
            else 
                numdays = numdays +1;
        }       
        int daycode = numdays % 7;
        return daycode; 
}

void printheader(int month, int year)
{
        printf("\n\tSun ");
        printf("\tMon ");
        printf("\tTue ");
}
```

Comment: Well you definitely know what you are doing, =P but I thought my functions were all fine as they were?

Comment: Is there problems with them? Or are you just neatening it up in some way?